# How to create a properties file via Dockerfile with dynamic values passed in docker run?

Tags: docker, environment-variables, properties-file

I am relatively new to Docker. Maybe this is a silly question.

My goal is to create an image which has a `system.properties` file, which as the name says, is a properties file with key value pairs.
I want to fill the values in this file **dynamically**. So I think the values need to be passed as environment variables to the Docker run command.

For example, if this is what i want in my `system.properties` file:

```
buildMode=true
source=/path1
```

I want to provide the values to this file dynamically, something like:

```
$ docker run -e BUILD_MODE=true -e SOURCE='/path1' my_image
```

But I'm stuck at how I can copy the values into the file. Any help will be appreciated.

*Note*: Base image is linux centos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you suspect, you need to create the actual file at runtime.  One pattern that’s useful in Docker is to write a dedicated entrypoint script that does any required setup, then launches the main container command.

If you’re using a “bigger” Linux distribution base, [envsubst](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html) is a useful tool for this.  (It’s part of the GNU toolset and isn’t available by default on Alpine base images, but on CentOS it should be.)  You might write a template file:

```
buildMode=${BUILD_MODE}
source=${SOURCE}
```

Then you can copy that template into your image:

```sh
...
WORKDIR /app
COPY ...
COPY system.properties.tmpl ./
COPY entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

The entrypoint script needs to run envsubst, then go on to run the command:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
envsubst <system.properties.tmpl >system.properties
exec "$@"
```

You can do similar tricks just using **sed**(1), which is more universally available, but requires potentially trickier regular expressions.

Comment: Thank you - copying file into APP directory makes sense.