# Access container_name in Dockerfile (from docker-compose)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have setup a docker-compose project which are creating multiple images:

```
cache_server:
    image: current_timezone/full-supervisord-cache-server:1.00
    container_name: renamed-varnish-cache
    networks:
      - network_frontend
    build:
      context: "./all-services/"
      dockerfile: "./cache-server/Dockerfile.cacheserver.varnish"
      args:
        - DOCKER_CONTAINER_USERNAME=username
    ports:
      - "6081:6081"
      - "6082:6082"
```

When I use `docker-compose up -f file1.yml file2.override.yml` I will then get the containers: in the case of above one it will be named : `renamed-varnish-cache`

In the corresponding Dockerfile (`./nginx-proxy/Dockerfile.proxy.nginx`) I want to be able use the `container_name` property defined in the `docker-compose.yml` shown above.

When the containers are created I want to update the Varnish configurations inline inside Dockerfile : `RUN sed -i "s|webserver_container_name|renamed-varnish-cache|g" /etc/varnish/default.vcl"`

For instance:

```
    backend webserver_container_name{
        .host = "webserver_container_name";
        .port = "8080";
    }
```

To: *I anticipate I will have to replace the `-` with `_` for the backend:*

```
    backend renamed_varnish_cache{
        .host = "renamed-varnish-cache";
        .port = "8080";
    }
```

Is there a way to receive the docker-compose named items as *variables inside Dockerfile?*

Comment: You can launch multiple containers off the same image, so you can't know what the eventual container names might be at image build time (in the Dockerfile).

Comment: I tried to infer in my question `docker-compose up -f file1.yml file2.override.yml` which means I **specify the container_name inside the docker-compose** file, in other words if I have multiple containers, I would use another override file.

I would have liked to then fill those dynamically.

Maybe I missed the concept that the image builds with the predefined name, and if you override the docker-compose files, they will still use the _old image_ and not _create a new image_ ; is that what you are trying to tell me?

Comment: "As soon as I run `docker-compose up -d`, it takes the old image and will not recreate a new image?"  Not sure if that you meant?  If that is the case, docker-compose usefulness is not that great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In core Docker, there are two separate concepts.  An *image* is a built version of some piece of software packaged together with its dependencies; a *container* is a running instance of an image.  There are separate `docker build` and `docker run` commands to build images and launch containers, and you can launch multiple containers from a single image.

Docker Compose wraps these concepts.  In particular, the `build:` block corresponds to the image-build step, and that is what invokes the Dockerfile.  **None of the other Compose options are available or visible inside the Dockerfile.**  You cannot access the `container_name:` or `environment:` variables or `volumes:` because those don't exist at this point in the build lifecycle; you also cannot contact other Compose services from inside the Dockerfile.

It's pretty common to have multiple containers run off the same image if they have largely the same code base but need a different top-level command.  One example is a Python Django application that needs Celery background workers; you'd have the same project structure but a different command for the Celery worker.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    image: my/django-app
  worker:
    image: my/django-app
    command: celery worker ...
```

Now with this stack you can `docker-compose build` to build the one image, and then run `docker-compose up` to launch both containers from that image.  (During the build you can't know what the container names will be, and there will be two container names so you can't just use one in the Dockerfile.)

At a design level, this means that you often can't include configuration-type settings in the image itself (other containers' hostnames, user IDs for host-shared filesystems).  If your application lets you specify these things as environment variables, that's the easiest option.  You can use bind mounts (`volumes:`) to inject whole config files.  If neither of these things work for you, you can [use an entrypoint script to rewrite the config file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54426069/10008173).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.  I have already been busy with working with entrypoint instead of `RUN` since your previous comment above hinted that I done something wrong.

Comment: As an additional question, I guess rather similar to this - could you please assist me there. As you can see from that question, I do use this concept you explained (base image to multiple child images), but somehow I really misinterpret what docker-compose could do for me. Could you please have a look at [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63262898/docker-reuse-docker-compose-configurations-for-different-projects) as well, as nobody every answered there.